# Fragment still exists after remove?

Tags: android, fragment

1 Add two fragments to FragmentManager

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm.beginTransaction();
ft1.add(containerId, fragment1, "fragment1");
ft1.addToBackStack(null);
ft1.commitAllowingStateLoss();

FragmentTransaction ft2 = fm.beginTransaction();
ft2.add(containerId, fragment2, "fragment2");
ft2.addToBackStack(null);
ft2.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

2 Change mobile setting 
    Developer Options-> Don't Keep Activities-> ON

3 Remove all fragments after activity was recreated

```
FragmentTransaction ft3 = fm.beginTransaction();
for(Fragment f : fm.getFragments())  ft3.remove(f); 
ft3.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

My question is why fm.findFragmentByTag("fragment1") is NOT null after remove?

minSdkVersion 17 
 targetSdkVersion 22 
 compileSdkVersion 22

Answer (score 14):

try this code for remove the fragment

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
trans.remove(myFrag);
trans.commit();
manager.popBackStack();
```

i think you have not add this method

```
manager.popBackStack();
```

or

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()
```

Comment: Works like charm !

Answer (score 4):

use `popBackStackImmediate()` instead of `popBackStack()` which insure fragment is removed from backstack immediately. transection's remove method does not remove fragment from backstack it just for transection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
    List<Fragment> list = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (list == null) {
        Log.e("TAg", "No existing fragments" );
    }

    for (Fragment frag : list)
    {
        // To save any of the fragments, add this check.
        // A tag can be added as a third parameter to the fragment when you commit it
        if (frag.getTag().equals("tag-name")) {
            continue;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I removed the fragment by using the tag as follows:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment1");
ft.remove(fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Now `findFragmentByTag()` should return null

Answer (score 0):

instead of the

```
ft1.add(containerId, fragment1, "fragment1");
```

try

```
ft1.replace(containerId, fragment1, "fragment1");
```

and use the

```
fragmentmanager.popBackStack();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should `commit` individual fragment remove transactions.

this code will commit after loop complete

```
for(Fragment f : fm.getFragments())  ft3.remove(f); 
ft3.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

instead of use `brackets`

```
for(Fragment f : fm.getFragments()){
 ft3.remove(f); 
 ft3.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          public  void popAll() {
            if (mFragmentManager != null) {
                if (!mOnPause && mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    if (isFragmentOnStack(HomeFragment.TAG_NAME))
                        mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(HomeFragment.TAG_NAME, 0);
                    else
                        mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null,
                                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                } else if (mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    mTransactionList.clear();
                    mTransactionList.add(new FragmentPopAll());
                }


 }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `commitNow` method instead of `commitAllowingStateLoss`, as it perform transaction synchronously